# Firebase : Can't resolve google auth and GoogleSignInResult libraries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just started with Android and I am looking in to using Google Firebase for Google Sign-In. Unfortunately I am unable to import

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot resolve symbol Auth
Cannot resolve symbol GoogleSignInResult
```

My Project `build.gradle` looks like

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

My Module `build.gradle` looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
.......
.......
.......
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}
```

Also following are the errors

```
Error:(229, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable disconnect_button
Error:(227, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_out_button
Error:(225, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_in_button
Error:(214, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(222, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(117, 45) error: package Auth does not exist
Error:(60, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Auth
Error:(210, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_out_and_disconnect
Error:(206, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mStatusTextView
Error:(201, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable firebase_status_fmt
Error:(200, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mStatusTextView
Error:(164, 35) error: package Auth does not exist
Error:(151, 44) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInActivity
Error:(204, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_out_and_disconnect
Error:(12, 39) error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api does not exist
Error:(198, 9) error: cannot find symbol method hideProgressDialog()
Error:(174, 13) error: package Auth does not exist
Error:(15, 46) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInResult
Error:(188, 13) error: package Auth does not exist
Error:(59, 108) error: incompatible types: LoginActivity cannot be converted to OnConnectionFailedListener
Error:(155, 25) error: cannot find symbol method hideProgressDialog()
Error:(200, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable google_status_fmt
Error:(206, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable signed_out
Error:(117, 13) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInResult
Error:(209, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_in_button
Error:(201, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mDetailTextView
Error:(207, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mDetailTextView
Error:(203, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable sign_in_button
Error:(136, 9) error: cannot find symbol method showProgressDialog()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please use 4 spaces to indent as code blocks instead of using the backtick method.

Comment: Try adding:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
to your gradle

Comment: Check my answer below it will solve your problem let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With this two dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

You also need to add one which is below. This is the part you need to include which is Play Services Auth that's it:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
```

And move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` below all this dependencies means at last:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @MuhammadHassanNiazi Glad it helped :).

Answer (score 0):

Include

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
```

If you are getting a build error complaining about duplicate files you can choose to exclude those files by adding the packagingOptions directive to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. Between i am updating the errors in the orignal post. Please take a look. Thanks for your time and effort.